# Boost.Python fails with static libraries

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I cannot seem to get the simple hello.cpp example in Boost.Python to work.

hello.cpp:

```
char const* greet()
{
   return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

I am using cmake with mingw-w64 and am not entirely sure of the difference between using the static and shared boost libraries. If the extension is linked with the shared library will the extension library have to be distributed with the boost library as well? I would like to only have to distribute a single dll. What is the difference between `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` and `Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME`? If either of these flags are set to `ON` the subsequent compilation will fail with undefined symbols. If they are both set to OFF a file called libhello_ext.dll is created. However, I cannot get python to use it with either `import hello_ext` or `import libhello_ext`.

This is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(hello VERSION 1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g")

set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR C:/boost_1_67_0/stage/x64/lib)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON)
find_package(Boost 1.67.0 REQUIRED python37)
if (Boost_FOUND)
    message(" Boost include directory found at ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message(" Boost libraries found at ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
else()
    message(" Boost not found")
    return()
endif()

find_package(PythonLibs 3.7 REQUIRED)
if (PYTHONLIBS_FOUND)
    message(" Python include directory found at ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message(" Python libraries found at ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}")
else()
    message(" Python not found")
endif()

set(SOURCE_FILES hello.cpp)
add_library(hello_ext SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_include_directories(hello_ext SYSTEM PRIVATE  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(hello_ext ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

This is the output for mingw32-make:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX shared library libhello_ext.dll
CMakeFiles\hello_ext.dir/objects.a(hello.cpp.obj): In function `PyInit_hello_ext':
C:/boost_1_67_0/libs/python/example/tutorial/hello.cpp:15: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5boost6python6detail11init_moduleER11PyModuleDefPFvvE'
CMakeFiles\hello_ext.dir/objects.a(hello.cpp.obj): In function `boost::python::type_info::name() const':
C:/boost_1_67_0/boost/python/type_id.hpp:160: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5boost6python6detail12gcc_demangleEPKc'
CMakeFiles\hello_ext.dir/objects.a(hello.cpp.obj): In function `boost::python::to_python_value<char const* const&>::operator()(char const* const&) const':
C:/boost_1_67_0/boost/python/converter/builtin_converters.hpp:157: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5boost6python9converter19do_return_to_pythonEPKc'
CMakeFiles\hello_ext.dir/objects.a(hello.cpp.obj): In function `void boost::python::def<char const* (*)()>(char const*, char const* (*)())':
C:/boost_1_67_0/boost/python/def.hpp:91: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5boost6python6detail17scope_setattr_docEPKcRKNS0_3api6objectES3_'
CMakeFiles\hello_ext.dir/objects.a(hello.cpp.obj): In function `boost::python::api::object boost::python::detail::make_function_aux<char const* (*)(), boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector1<char const*> >(char const* (*)(), boost::python::default_call_policies const&, boost::mpl::vector1<char const*> const&)':
C:/boost_1_67_0/boost/python/make_function.hpp:38: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5boost6python7objects15function_objectERKNS1_11py_functionE'
CMakeFiles\hello_ext.dir/objects.a(hello.cpp.obj): In function `boost::python::objects::py_function_impl_base::py_function_impl_base()':
C:/boost_1_67_0/boost/python/object/py_function.hpp:20: undefined reference to `__imp__ZTVN5boost6python7objects21py_function_impl_baseE'
CMakeFiles\hello_ext.dir/objects.a(hello.cpp.obj): In function `boost::python::objects::caller_py_function_impl<boost::python::detail::caller<char const* (*)(), boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector1<char const*> > >::~caller_py_function_impl()':
C:/boost_1_67_0/boost/python/object/py_function.hpp:30: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5boost6python7objects21py_function_impl_baseD2Ev'
CMakeFiles\hello_ext.dir/objects.a(hello.cpp.obj): In function `boost::python::converter::expected_pytype_for_arg<char const*>::get_pytype()':
C:/boost_1_67_0/boost/python/converter/pytype_function.hpp:67: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5boost6python9converter8registry5queryENS0_9type_infoE'
C:/boost_1_67_0/boost/python/converter/pytype_function.hpp:70: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK5boost6python9converter12registration25expected_from_python_typeEv'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\hello_ext.dir\build.make:88: libhello_ext.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:72: CMakeFiles/hello_ext.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:83: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Hello! Did you find the solution of this trouble? I faced with it just now and can't find troubleshot...

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason, the naming convention must be forced for Boost Python (and only for Boost Python, other Boost modules don't need this) in Windows (not in Linux nor MacOSX).

In summary, you need to add:

```
add_definitions(/DBOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB)
```

to your CMake config file. Otherwise, your linker will try to use `boost_python37-vc141-mt-x64-1_70.lib` (the import library associated to the DLL, `boost_python37-vc141-mt-x64-1_70.dll`) instead of `libboost_python37-vc141-mt-x64-1_70.lib`, which is the "real" static library (Stupid Windows and its weird convention to use the same extension for Import libraries and Static libraries).